# SQL sum and group values from two tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to group sales data based on a sellers' name. The name is available in another table. My tables look like this:

**InvoiceRow:**

```
+-----------+----------+-----+----------+
| InvoiceNr | Title    | Row |  Amount  |
+-----------+----------+-----+----------+
|  1        | Chair    |  1  |  2000.00 |
|  2        | Sofa     |  1  |  1500.00 |
|  2        | Cushion  |  2  |  2000.00 |
|  3        | Lamp     |  1  |  6500.00 |
|  4        | Table    |  1  |  -500.00 |
+-----------+----------+-----+----------+
```

**InvoiceHead:**

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| InvoiceNr | Seller   | Date       |
+-----------+----------+------------+
|  1        | Adam     | 2016-01-01 |
|  2        | Lisa     | 2016-01-04 |
|  3        | Adam     | 2016-01-08 |
|  4        | Carl     | 2016-01-17 |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

**The query that I'm working with currently looks like this:**

```
SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM InvoiceRow
WHERE InvoiceNr IN (
  SELECT InvoiceNr
  FROM InvoiceHead
  WHERE Date >= '2016-01-01' AND Date < '2016-02-01'
)
```

This works and will sum the values of all rows of all invoices (total sales) in the month of january.

**What I want to do is a sales summary grouped by each sellers' name. Something like this:**

```
+----------+------------+
| Seller   | Amount     |
+----------+------------+
| Adam     | 8500.00    |
| Lisa     | 3500.00    |
| Carl     | -500.00    |
+----------+------------+
```

And after that maybe even grouped by month (but that's not part of this question, I'm hoping to be able to figured that out if I solve this).

I've tried all kinds of joins but I end up with a lot of duplicates, and I'm not sure how to SUM and group at the same time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is a pretty basic `join` with `group by` query.

Comment: You should try JOIN on the `InvoiceNr` field - Also, in your WHERE InvoiceNr, select Seller field as well, and `Group By`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT seller, SUM(amount) FROM InvoiceRow 
JOIN InvoiceHead 
ON InvoiceRow.InvoiceNr = InvoiceHead.InvoiceNr
GROUP BY InvoiceHead.seller;
```

OR If you want to between two date. Try This

```
SELECT seller, SUM(amount) FROM InvoiceRow 
JOIN InvoiceHead 
ON InvoiceRow.InvoiceNr = InvoiceHead.InvoiceNr
WHERE InvoiceHead.Date >= '2016-01-01' AND InvoiceHead.Date < '2016-02-01'
GROUP BY InvoiceHead.seller;
```

Comment: Wow, 3 replies in less than 5 minutes. I've followed yours as it was closes to the syntax I had.

One issue i'm having is that the summed amount is different after joining than it was before. Something is wrong, and I get the feeling that the join creates duplicates that are summed along the other rows which increases the amount. I.e. if I use my original query and compare the SUM value to the ones I get after the join and group, they don't match. What I'm saying is that the amount per seller doesn't equal the amount I get before joining and grouping.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to join the tables, filter result by date as you need and then make grouping:

```
select
   H.Seller,
   sum(R.Amount) as Amount
from InvoiceHead as H
    left outer join InvoiceRow as R on R.InvoiceNr = H.InvoiceNr
where H. Date >= '2016-01-01' AND H.Date < '2016-02-01' 
group by H.Seller
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.seller,sum(s.amount)
FROM invoiceRow s join InvoiceHead t
ON s.invoiceNr = t.invoiceNr 
group by t.seller
```

You should just sum them up. If date range is necessary, you can add a where clause after the ON clause and filter you dates like this:

```
SELECT t.seller,sum(s.amount)
FROM invoiceRow s join InvoiceHead t
ON s.invoiceNr = t.invoiceNr 
WHERE t.date between '01-01-2016' and '31-01-2016' 
group by t.seller
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this once:

```
    SELECT ih.Seller,   
     (
        SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM invoicerow ir
        INNER JOIN invoicehead ih1
            ON (ir.InvoiceNr = ih1.InvoiceNr)
            WHERE ih1.Seller = ih.Seller
        ) AS Amount 
    FROM invoicehead ih 
    GROUP BY  ih.Seller
```